# Change button on click for few seconds

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I would like to change a button's image source for a few seconds on click.

For now i have this:

```
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('buttonImg').src='images/button2.png';},5000);
```

But what this does is changing the image after 5 seconds instead of for 5 seconds.
I can't figure out how to change the setTimeout function to do so

Answer (score 3):

The function `setTimeout` execute the first parameters after a delay given in the second parameter. So first change your image imediatly:

```
document.getElementById('buttonImg').src='images/button2.png';
```

Then just reset to previous image after a delay of 5s (5000ms):

```
setTimeout(function(){
     document.getElementById('buttonImg').src='images/button1.png';
},5000);
```

Comment: That did the job, idk how i missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this!

```
document.getElementById('buttonImg').src='images/button2.png';
 setTimeout(function() {
     document.getElementById('buttonImg').src='[the source of the original image]';
 } ,5000);
```

Comment: It is better to explain so the OP can understand what he did wrong :) but that is the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the original image so that you can replace with that after `5000` milliseconds. Something like this,

```js
function clickBtn(){
 var originalSrc = document.getElementById('buttonImg').src;
 document.getElementById('buttonImg').src = 'https://www.freeiconspng.com/minicovers/submit-button-png-18.png'
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('buttonImg').src=originalSrc;
  },5000);
}
```

```html
<img id='buttonImg' src='https://www.freeiconspng.com/minicovers/submit-button-png-9.png' onclick='clickBtn()' />
```